# How to keep updating a table which is created from multiple tables with different update times

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a table by joining multiple source tables.

This table should have new entries or updates in last 24 hours from the source tables.

I will insert the new data and delete the updated data and reinsert it.

The problem is that the source tables are not updated at the same time.

What is the best way to keep this table up to date with the data from source tables.

Following example code will work if table 'a' is updated but what if table 'b' and 'c' are updated later how can I update my new table as well to get the updated fields from those tables?

I am using snowflake database.

```
insert into combined_table
select a.id, max(b.shipment_date), b.quantity, c.status 
from table_a a 
left join table_b b on a.id=b.a_id 
left join table_c c on b.id=c.b_id 
a.record_updated_at > dateadd(HOUR, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
group by a.id, c.status

table_a
id  created_at   updated_at 
1   2019-02-14   2019-02-16

table_b
id  a_id  shipment_date  quantity created_at  updated_at  
3   1     2019-02-15     5        2019-02-15  2019-02-16

table_c
id   b_id   status    created_at   updated_at
5    3      Inactive  2019-02-15   2019-02-15

combined_table
id shipment_date  quantity status
1  2019-02-15     5        Inactive
```

if for example table_b quantity changes from 5 to 7 and in table_c status change to 'Active' how can I update this in my delta table?

```
table_b
id  a_id  shipment_date  quantity created_at  updated_at  
3   1     2019-02-15     5        2019-02-15  2019-02-16

table_c
id   b_id   status    created_at   updated_at
5    3      Active    2019-02-15   2019-02-16
```

Combined table should look like following. What is the best way?

```
combined_table
id shipment_date  quantity status
1  2019-02-15     7        Active
```

Comment: You can create a view on top of this sql and do a periodic refresh / set a periodic refresh

Comment: How will it help with getting the updated data from the joined tables?

Comment: view will be auto refreshed when there is a change in tables.

Comment: View will not be a good idea as these tables are big. Performance won't be good.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a look at Tasks and Streams in Snowflake.  These would allow you to setup a stream on each of your tables to capture changes that have occurred there, and then run a task against those streams on a scheduled basis IF there are changes available.

Comment: Tasks and Streams in Snowflake sounds interesting. But how would it keep all the columns in my delta table up to date  from the source tables?

Comment: The streams are your delta tables.  Take a look at the documentation here.  It may not be the only thing you need to do based on your situation, but to have a stream tracking changes means you don't need to look at update dates to determine if something has changed.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html

Comment: I think it was wrong of me to call the table  as delta. It is created by joins of a, b and c. And I want keep it up to date with all the delta from source tables

Comment: Ok - so it's not solving your timing and join issues, but it's worth looking at instead of leveraging the update date to determine changes.

Comment: Yes for keeping track CDC it is pretty good. I will look into it more. Does it cost more to use?

Comment: Nope.  It's currently in Public Preview, btw, but I'd expect it to go GA soon.  In theory, you could JOIN 3 streams together, and when there is a resulting record, you could MERGE that into the fact.  However, that would reset your CDC, so you'd lose everything else.  Is it possible to just update each column separately?  Like if you get a change from 1 source table, just update those fields, or does it have to be a change in all 3 source tables to prompt a change?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem I think you may want to change those joins to `full join`s. This will cover the case where an ID may exist in `b`, `c` or `d` but doesn't yet exist in `a`. After that you can use a `where` predicate with a bunch of `or` statements to check each table for changes.

Here is a simplified example of what I think you need:

```sql
-- set up the example tables
create or replace temporary table table_a (id number, record_updated_at timestamp_ntz);
create or replace temporary table table_b (id number, shipment_date date, record_updated_at timestamp_ntz);
create or replace temporary table table_c (id number, status varchar, record_updated_at timestamp_ntz);

-- add some sample data
insert overwrite into table_a values (1, '2019-01-01T01:00:00'), (2, '2019-01-01T04:00:00');
insert overwrite into table_b values (1, '2019-01-01','2019-01-01T01:00:00'), (3, '2019-01-02','2019-01-01T03:00:00');
insert overwrite into table_c values (1, 'shipped','2019-01-01T01:00:00');

-- return any records that have changed in any table
select
    a.id a_id, 
    a.record_updated_at a_updated,
    b.id b_id, 
    b.record_updated_at b_updated,
    b.shipment_date,
    c.id c_id,
    c.status,
    c.record_updated_at c_updated
from table_a a
full join table_b b on a.id = b.id
full join table_c c on a.id = c.id 
where a.record_updated_at > '2019-01-01T02:00:00'
    or b.record_updated_at  > '2019-01-01T02:00:00'
    or c.record_updated_at > '2019-01-01T02:00:00'
```

Alternatively you can do what Mike has mentioned and used tasks + streams. This is a pretty neat way of doing it too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at new STREAMS ON VIEW feature.